# How to start a video with JavaScript when a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to trigger a video to play if the key 'm' is pressed on the keyboard. So far I have managed to place the video correctly but I'm not being able to make the JavaScript code work properly.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('Experiment04');
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keycode === 77) {
    return video
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #Experiment04 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-height: 80%;
      min-width: 80%;
      z-index: 0;
      mix-blend-mode: screen;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <!--Experiment04-->


  <video id="Experiment04" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
                <source src="Experiment 04.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Video not supported
                
            </video>

  <script src="Untitled-3.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Am I placing the js link in the html code in the wrong place? or do I have code errors?

(If you couldn't tell already I am really new to all of this. any type of help would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: Instead of `return video`, use `video.play();`. Read more about the `video` API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return video`, use `video.play();`. Read more about the `video` API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs).

Also, use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (which you didn't capitalize correctly by the way) because `.keyCode` is deprecated.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('Experiment04');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "m") {
     video.play();
   }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video Test</title>
  <style>              
     #Experiment04 {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       height:300px;
       min-height: 50%;
       min-width: 50%;
       z-index: 0;
       mix-blend-mode: screen;
    }
  </style>   
</head>
<body>
  <video id="Experiment04" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
     <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Video not supported
  </video>
  <script src="Untitled-3.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its useless to return the video i the event callback; nothing will be done with it. Instead, call its `play()` method:

```js
    var video = document.getElementById('Experiment04');   
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.keycode === 77) {
            video.play();
        }
    })
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
                
                 #Experiment04 {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    min-height: 80%;
                    min-width: 80%;
                    z-index: 0;
                    mix-blend-mode: screen;
                }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
         <!--Experiment04-->
    
    
            <video id="Experiment04" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
                <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/9/9e/CJK_Stroke_order_intergrated_into_HTML5_webpage.webm/CJK_Stroke_order_intergrated_into_HTML5_webpage.webm.480p.vp9.webm" type="video/webm">
                Video not supported
                
            </video>
        
        <script src="Untitled-3.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```